# Spock: using a Mock inside a "where" clause table?

Tags: java, mocking, spock

I am trying to use ia mocked object in the table of a "where" clause. Basically something like this:

```
def "my test"(){

    given:
    InjectedObject1 inj1 = Mock()
    InjectedObject2 inj2 = Mock()
    SystemUnderTest system = new System(inj1, inj2)
    MockedObject mocked = Mock()

    inj1.someMethod() >> list  // this will be a list of MockedObject

    when:
    system.execute()

    then:
    n * inj2.someOtherMethod()

    where:
    list             | n
    [mocked]         | 0
    [mocked, mocked] | 1
}
```

This doesn't work because the "where" clause is executed before the "given" clause, so `mocked` doesn't exist yet when it is first referenced. How do I overcome this? `mocked` in used only is this test so I'd like to avoid creating it outside of this method.

Note that this is a simplified example, there are actually more interactions, and other columns in the table that have an influence on `n` - which makes the table syntax very handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor the method to something like:

```
...
inj1.someMethod() >> [mocked] * numReturned
...
then:
numCalled * inj2.someOtherMethod()

where:
numReturned | numCalled
1           | 0
2           | 1
```

In other words, specify (just) the parts in the where-block and assemble them in the method body. This is a common solution.

Usually, another solution is to shuffle the objects to be used in the where-block into `@Shared` fields. The 'too big scope' problem can be mitigated by having multiple small specs in the same file. However, this solution won't work for mocks because mocks can't be `@Shared`.

Comment: I thought about doing this and it would work in my case, but what if this list had to be more complex (like, mixing different mocked objects, in different orders etc.)? Sure, as a generalisation of your solution you could use an int in the "where" table and have a switch in the "given" clause to generate the required mocks, but that kinda defeats the purpose of the nice table syntax...

Comment: Every tool has its limitations. Feel free to submit a feature request at http://issues.spockframework.org.

Comment: [Done](http://code.google.com/p/spock/issues/detail?id=224) :)
Thank you for your work on Spock @peter.